# How do I use shouldReceive on a function that was called by another?

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, laravel-5.4, mockery

I have functions like so:

```
// $value could be an array or SomeClass type
public function foo($key, $value) 
{
    // some code
    if ($value instanceof SomeClass) {
        $value = $this->bar($value);
    }
    // some code
}

protected function bar(SomeClass $value) 
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Now In my test I have something like this:

```
{
    $suppliedValue = [];

    $mock = ... // create mock
    $mock->shouldReceive('foo')->withArgs(
        // first arg should be an int or string
        // second arg should be an array or SomeClass object
    );

    if (typeOf($suppliedValue) === 'array') {
        $mock->shouldNotReceive('bar');
    } else {
        $mock->shouldReceive('bar');
    }

    $mock->aFunctionThatCallsFoo($suppliedValue);
}
```

However it does not seem to work, no matter what value is supplied to `foo()`, it does not trigger the `shouldReceive()` / `shouldNotReceive()` on `bar()`.

What am I missing here? I feel as if I am misunderstanding something fundamental about mocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to solve this via mock, but I used a [Spy](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/spies.html) instead.

```
$spy = Mockery::spy(TheClass::class)
              ->makePartial()
              ->shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods();

$spy->aFunctionThatCallsFoo($suppliedValue);
$spy->shouldHaveReceived('foo')
    ->withArgs(/* args */); 
$spy->shouldHaveReceived('bar');
```

I end up creating 2 test functions instead of using `if else` for the type of `$suppliedValue`, where the other one calls `shouldNotHaveReceived()`